# how to convert "+=" to operator in ruby

Tags: ruby

I can convert `"+"` , `"-"` or `"/"` to operator use `2.send("-",3)`

but it does not work with `"+="`

```
a = 2
a += 2 #=> 4

a = 2
a.send("+=", 4) #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `+=' for 2:Fixnum
```

I have tried to convert symbol first ; but not works too;

how to fix this?

Comment: `+=`, `-=` are not operators. When ruby sees `x += 1` she converts that to `x = x + 1` and then evaluates that. `+=` (and the others) are provided merely for the convenience of the coder.

Comment: thank u @CarySwoveland

Comment: I closed it since in the linked answer’s comments there is a perfect answer.

Comment: `+=` (and the others) is called *abbreviated assignment*.

Comment: There is no such method called `+=`, so you can't `send` it.

Comment: @mudasobwa I've reopened the question. Although there is an answer in a comment, I think this question deserves an actual answer.

Comment: @Stefan sure, I doubted whether it should be closed or not and you made the right choice for me :)

Comment: The `send` method already automatically converts strings to symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2.send("-", 3)` works, because `-` is a method and `2` responds to that method:

```
2.respond_to?('-') #=> true
```

`=` and `+=` on the other hand are not methods:

```
2.respond_to?('=')  #=> false
2.respond_to?('+=') #=> false
```

And even if `=` was a valid method<sup>1</sup>, then

```
a = 2
a.send("=", 4)
```

would be equivalent to:

```
2.send("=", 4)
```

or simply:

```
2 = 4
```

In other words: it would redefine `2` as `4`, something Ruby doesn't allow you to do.

This is because variables (like `a` above) are not objects. `a.send` doesn't send a message to the variable `a`, but to the object, `a` is referring to (`2` in the example).

The same applies to [abbreviated assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment) like `+=`:

```
a = 2
a += 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = 2
a = a + 2
```

You can just rewrite it as:

```
a = 2
a = a.send("+", 2)
```

The assignment is not part of the method invocation.

---

<sup>1</sup> you can actually define a method `=` via `define_method`:

```
class Foo
  define_method('=') { |other| puts "`=' called with #{other}" }
end
```

But it is just an ordinary method. In particular, it does not and can not alter the variable the object was assigned-to or the object's identity:

```
 f = Foo.new
 #=> #<Foo:0x007ff20c0eeda8>
 f.send('=', 123)
 # `=' called with 123
 #=> nil
 f
 #=> #<Foo:0x007ff20c0eeda8>
```